# Gorm Adds Double Quotes Around Name of Table and Columns

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I am using GORM with Go and when I try to do an insert, it fails because GORM surrounds the table and column names with double quotes, and hence the insert statement becomes invalid. Relevant code is as follows:

```
type Record struct {
   Company string `json:"-" gorm:"column:company"`
   Category string `json:"-" gorm:"column:category"`
}

err := dm.postgresDB.Transaction(func(tx *gorm.DB) error {
   if err := tx.Create(&rd).Error; err != nil {
```

I am not sure why this is happening. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Which database are you using? Quoting column names is a standard practice to avoid keyword conflict (for example if you're using `database` as a column name), if the query failed it might be your database not supporting this double quote syntax

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL. The error I get is as follows: **ERROR: relation "records" does not exist (SQLSTATE 42P01)**. The name of the table is **records** and not **"records"**. It does the same to all field names.

Comment: Figured out that this occurs because my schema is not public. Hence, records needs to be prepended with the name of the schema. But how do I set this using GORM?

Comment: I figured this out. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: hi @Foobar how could you figured out of this problem, could you explain it ?